# In Clojure, how to write a factory with variable number of arguments

Tags: clojure

I would like to create a factory, in `clojure` where the number of arguments to the creator varies at run time.

For example:

```
(defn create-long-document [direction]
  (str "long document " direction))

(defn create-short-document[]
  "short document")

(def creator-map {
 :english create-short-document
 :hebrew  create-long-document
})
(def additional-arg-map {
 :english nil
 :hebrew "rtl"
})

 (defn create-document [language]
  (let [creator (language creator-map) arg (language additional-arg-map)]
    (if arg (creator arg) (creator))))


(println (create-document :hebrew)); long document rtl
(println (create-document :english)); short document
```

I am looking for an **elegant** way to rewrite the body of `create-document`. I want to get rid of the `if`. Maybe by introducing a smart macro?

Please share you ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest having your additional arguments specified as collections:

```
(def additional-arg-map {
  :english []
  :hebrew  ["rtl"]})
```

Then you can use [apply](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply) in your create-document function, something like:

```
(defn create-document [language]
  (let [creator (creator-map language)
        args    (additional-arg-map language)]
   (apply creator args)))
```

Note that an alternative (or perhaps complementary?) approach would be to define a variable-arity function if you want to allow the caller to provide specific extra arguments, e.g. something like:

```
(defn create-document
  ([language]
    .....handle no argument.....)
  ([language arg]
    .....handle 1 argument.....)
  ([language arg & more-args]
    .....handle more than one argument.....))
```

Comment: No need to allow the caller to provide specific extra arguments. In my case all the extra arguments must be hidden from the caller.

Answer (score 2):

I guess [multimethods](http://clojure.org/multimethods) would result in cleaner code. Using the same definitions for `create-long-document` and `create-short-document` you wrote:

```
; change identity to something more sophisticated 
; if you want sanity checks on input:
(defmulti create-document identity)

(defmethod create-document :default [lang] "language not supported")

(defmethod create-document :english [lang] (create-short-document))

(defmethod create-document :hebrew [lang] (create-long-document "rtl"))
```

Then, `create-document` will work as expected:

```
user=> (create-document :hebrew)
"long document rtl"
user=> (create-document :english)
"short document"
user=> (create-document :italian)
"language not supported"
```

In this way the dispatch logic is provided by the multimethods API, without the need for you to write your own dispatch function. The good thing of this approach is extensibility: supporting a new language only requires a new `defmethod`.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that if the code of `create-document` became a little bit richer, you  would have to duplicate the code in  each instance of the multimethod.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're able to factor out the common parts to some external functions

Answer (score 1):

I guess it could be as simple as :

```
(defn create-long-document [direction]
  (str "long document " direction))

(defn create-short-document[]
  "short document")

(def creator-map {
 :english #(create-short-document)
 :hebrew  #(create-long-document "rtl")
})

(defn create-document [language]
    ((creator-map language))
  )
```

Comment: This is not an elegant solution because the creator-map is **aware** of the way the functions it defines are called. There is a coupling between creator-map and create document: For instance, if create-document wanted to discard the additional arguments, one would need to modify creator-map also.

Comment: Somewhere you will need to have coupling. In your code it was in the create-document function itself. There is no code in real world that doesn't have "no coupling" at all